# InstallShield: Setting a Custom Action's Property Value from a Release Property

Tags: build-process, installshield, installshield-2010

I'm trying to automate InstallShield from my build process, and I need to set a type 51 Custom Action's Property Value from my Release's Product Configuration Flags property. What is the syntax (something in square brackets?) to do that?

*From here...*
[image]

*...to here:*
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to do a string replace on the InstallShield project to pull this off:

1) Under **General Information** | **Project File Format**, set the format to "XML", and save the project.

2) Next write a script to search the xml file for the name of your custom action, and replace the value with your Product Configuration Flags.

We've used this straightforward technique to change a number of properties at build time, including version numbers.

Answer (score 3):

InstallShield also has an automation interface.  FYI:
http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm

> For advanced developers, InstallShield
>   exposes a COM interface that allows
>   you to perform many of the same tasks
>   from a program, such as a Visual
>   Basic� executable, or a script, such
>   as a VBScript file in Windows
>   Scripting Host. By calling methods,
>   setting properties, accessing
>   collections, and so on, through the
>   automation interface, you can open a
>   project and modify its features and
>   component data in many of the same
>   ways that you would in the
>   InstallShield interface.

[MSI Tip: Building Releases with the InstallShield Automation Interface](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/webdocuments/PDF/building-with-automation.pdf)

There's a bit of a learning curve, but once you've got it, it more reliable and robust than editing the XML file manually.